# MySQL Workbench crash on start on Windows

Tags: mysql, .net, crash, runtime, workbench

I`ve just installed my MySQL Workbench and it crashes on start and i really dont know what to do with it. Error codes from Event Log :

```
Application Error
Application that causes trobule: MySQLWorkbench.exe
version: 6.2.3.12312, 
time signature: 0x541717ae
Name of the module that causes error: KERNELBASE.dll, 
version: 6.1.7601.18409, 
time signature: 0x5315a05a
exception code: 0xe0434352
error shift: 0x000000000000940d
ID of process that cause trobule: 0x8c0
Hour of launching the application that causes error: 0x01cffc736e910602
Path of the applicatin that causes error: D:\Programy\MySQL Workbench 6.2\MySQLWorkbench.exe
Path of the module that causes error:  C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Raport id: ae1d15f1-6866-11e4-8572-20689d5ba829
```

And

```
.NET Runtime
Application: MySQLWorkbench.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at MySQL.GUI.Workbench.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a reinstall of Workbench is needed.

Comment: tried many times, same result

Comment: Same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864653/mysql-workbench-crash-on-start-on-windows/61006558

Answer (score 13):

got same error. found "_README_FOR_ZIP_PACKAGE.txt" file in "mysql-workbench-community-6.2.4-winx64-noinstall.zip." file says

```
MySQL Workbench needs the following prerequisites:

Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17113)
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)
```

installed both. and now, it works. hope this information can help somebody.

Comment: Thank you - I pulled my hair out before found your solution. I was misssing: Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Answer (score 10):

Install Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer) from this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.6.html)  , even if your are using 64 bit operating system. MySQL Installer is 32 bit, but will install both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Pundeet. That solution worked. Thank you very much.  If the 32-bit version should be used on 64-bit machines do you know why a 64-bit version is included on the download page?

Comment: Not sure! They may have started putting it in an organized way now.

Comment: saved my time coz the website is much complex to find the appropriate version

Comment: I'm glad it helped you save your time.

Comment: Heads up, this is still true 1 and a half year later

Answer (score 4):

Hi Please install the MSVC 2013 runtime redistributables from MS: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: This one worked for me. I wonder why it was working in the past, i.e. who/what has uninstalled that requirement from my workstation?. Anyway the answer should be clarified in that you need to install **both** the X86 version and the x64 version (if you are on a 64-bit Windows). If you are on a 32-bit Windows I bet you can get away with only installing the x86 version.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am on Win 7 64-bit, I only installed the 64-bit (x64) version of Visual Studio 2013, and got this error.

How I was able to get past this was:

1) Uninstalling MySQL Workbench, and everything else, except for the MySQL Installer.

2) Installing the 32-bit (x86) version of Visual Studio 2013 (in addition to the 64-bit version)

3) Adding MySQL Workbench, and the other connectors/utilities I wanted.

I'm not sure whether you need both 32-bit or 64-bit, but having both worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I use version Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive

(mysql-workbench-community-6.2.5-winx64-noinstall.zip)

Try installing [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench 8.0.... 5 years later, same poor installation doc...

```
Faulting application name: MySQLWorkbench.exe, version: 8.0.19.0, time stamp: 0x5df6944b
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
at MySQL.GUI.Workbench.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

... from
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98207

prerequisites:

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
- Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019

No links on MySQL page but the VC can be found at the bottom under "Other Tools and Frameworks" ... 
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/