# MySQL configuration stops at starting server

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-server-2003

Currently trying to install `MySQL 5.6.26` on a `Windows Server 2003 R2 Service Pack 2`, during the installation, it stops at the starting server step, tried following [this question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970454/mysql-configuration-stops-at-starting-server), but when I tried starting the service, I get a "

> could not start the MySQL56 service on Local Computer. Error 1067: The
>   Process terminated unexpectedly

and all solutions I read didn't really work, can anyone help?

EDIT:- Would like to add that MySQL was installed before, but I removed it to allow the installation of the new one, if that helps in any way (the newer sql is assigned to the same port as the old one)

Comment: Are your permissions properly setup? Is UAC a problem?

Comment: Check that the port that MySQL is set to bind to is available and not in use by another instance or program. It's 3306 by default.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL installer in their site is ambiguous and makes it difficult for people to select the proper installer. I am afraid you have chosen a wrong installer for your machine. You can refer to [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30611150/1688683) of mine for a similar problem in another post.

Comment: thank you, but i did install the x86 version, actually can't find an installer for the x64